# copy multiple text-area contents with same id to clipboard using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, textarea, bootstrap-modal

I have 3 bootstrap modals with individual textareas displaying checked box values in textareas in the respective modal's textarea.

(I have a jquery capturing the checkbox values and putting them in the respective texareas. so it is working fine)

But I have put a copy button in each modal which opens a onclick even that points to a function to copy the respective textarea contents to clipboard. But only the first modal values are copied. When I click the copy buttons on the other modals, the values are not copied. Is there something that i'm missing.

the textarea is capturing the `checkid` from the divs. so the textarea is having id as checkid. the copy button is actioned to copy the textarea contents. but the copy button from the first modal works and not other modal.

```js
function CopyNotes() {

var DataSet = document.getElementByID('checkid').value; 

window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet);

}


/* copying checkid */

$("#button1").click(function() { var p=$("#MaybeResolved #checkid"); $(p).html("Cx Verified " + '\n' + "The Following sports I play");
 $.each($("input[name='Sport']:checked"), function() { 
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()); });
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n --------------------------------------------------------------\n Thank you see you again. \n --------------------------------------------------------------'); 
 }); 

//Touch does not respond 
$("#button2").click(function() { var p=$("#Resolved #checkid"); $(p).html("Cx Verified " + '\n' + "The Following sports I play");
 $.each($("input[name='Sport']:checked"), function() { 
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()); });
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n --------------------------------------------------------------\n Thank you see you again! \n --------------------------------------------------------------'); 
 });
 
$("#button3").click(function() { var p=$("#Unresolved #checkid"); $(p).html("Cx Verified " + '\n' + "The Following sports I play");
 $.each($("input[name='Sport1']:checked"), function() { 
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()); });
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n --------------------------------------------------------------\n Thanks for contacting us.\n . \n --------------------------------------------------------------'); 
 });

$("#button4").click(function() { var p=$("#MaybeResolved #checkid"); $(p).html("Cx Verified " + '\n' + "The Following sports I play:");
 $.each($("input[name='Sport1']:checked"), function() { 
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n' + $(this).val()); });
 $(p).html($(p).html() + '\n --------------------------------------------------------------\n Thank you see you again. \n --------------------------------------------------------------'); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap modal 1 -->

<textarea class="form-control" id="checkid" style="min-width: 100%" rows = "20">
</textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="button" id="copy-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="button" title="Copy to Clipboard" onclick = "CopyNotes()">Copy</button>

<!-- bootstrap modal 2 -->
<textarea class="form-control" id="checkid" style="min-width: 100%" rows = "20">
</textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="button" id="copy-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="button" title="Copy to Clipboard" onclick = "CopyNotes()">Copy</button>

<!-- bootstrap modal 3 -->

<textarea class="form-control" id="checkid" style="min-width: 100%" rows = "20">
</textarea>
<button class="btn btn-success btn-md" type="button" id="copy-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="button" title="Copy to Clipboard" onclick = "CopyNotes()">Copy</button>



<!---- Divs that get check box ids -->


<!--- div 1 -->
<form>
  <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport"> Football</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="sport"> Baseball</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport"> Cricket</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport"> Boxing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport"> Racing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport"> Swimming</label>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>
<button  id = "button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >I play these games</button>
  <button  id = "button2" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">I dont play these games</button>

<!--- div 2-->

<form>
  <h3>Select your favorite sports:</h3>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="football" name="sport1"> Football</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="baseball" name="spor1t"> Baseball</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="cricket" name="sport1"> Cricket</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="boxing" name="sport1"> Boxing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="racing" name="sport1"> Racing</label>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="swimming" name="sport1"> Swimming</label>
  <br>
  <button type="button">Get Values</button>
</form>
<button  id = "button3" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" >I play these games</button>
  <button  id = "button4" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">I dont play these games</button>


 <!-- div3--->
<!-- other div and so on.--->
<!--- the content is similar but also has addition checkboxes. -->
```

Comment: try to give different id name for text areas

Comment: Same IDs within same page is a very bad idea!!!

Comment: I have 3 buttons for each divs(there are many divs)  that has checkboxes in them. There is a jquery that captures the values under an ID `checkid`. Then comes the 3 bootstrap modals that display the values based on the buttons clicked. The bs modals have texares in them to display the values. there is a copy button in them to copy the the contents to the clipboard. But the copy buttons works for the fist modal and not for the other modals.

Answer (score 0):

Element id's are supposed to be unique. JavaScript attaches only to the first selector because it expects only one element. Use class instead!

Comment: But the class is also the same as I'm using bootstrap in the textareas. The reason why I'm using the same id in the textareas is because the checkid hold the selected checkbox values and then based on the buttons in the divs, the checkboxes are appended with some pre-entered text and put in the textarea. Is there any other way. @sadpanda

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your IDs should all have unique names, that's just how IDs are meant to be used.

To answer your question on how to get all the values from multiple textareas, you could instead target your class.

```
var DataSet = document.getElementsByClassName("form-control");
```

With this your DataSet variable will contain an array of your textarea values that you can access like this.

```
DataSet[0].value;
DataSet[1].value;
DataSet[2].value;
```

I'm not sure this is what you are looking for though, since you have 3 textareas and 3 buttons. But changing your IDs to be unique, your original code could also be used to individually target your 3 separate textareas with a little repetition.

Comment: is it possible for you to modify the code. so does the declaration come out the click function. and how about the dataset[]. is the following code correct ` window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet[]); ` or ` window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet[0]); ` sorry not that kind of a pro in javascript. @Toga

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I'm now using one modal to display the checkbox values. Then using a jquery to clear the textarea and displaying based on button clicks. Now the copy fiction has only one selector and the contents are copied.
Now can someone convert this to jquery syntax.  Thanks in advance.

```js
function CopyNotes() {

var DataSet = document.getElementByID('checkid').value; 

window.clipboardData.setData("TEXT", DataSet);
}
```